# "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute" when creating class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have defined a simple class but recieve the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bar'` when trying to use it. What am I doing wrong?

```
def Foo():
    a = 0
    def bar(self):
        return self.a

f = Foo()
f.bar() # error
```

Comment: `Foo` is a function, not a class.

Answer (score 5):

This is the syntax to define a *function*

```
def Foo():
```

to define a *class* you'd say

```
class Foo:
```

Answer (score 3):

### Your problem

`Foo` is defined with `def`, which makes it a **function**, not a class. If you want `Foo` to contain functions, then it needs to be a **class**.

### Solution

Use the `class` keyword to turn `Foo` into a class:

```
class Foo():
```

Comment: What is the difference between `class Foo:` and `class Foo():`?

Comment: @PickleProgrammer There is none. Both create an old-style class in Python2 and a class in Python3.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to create a class, try :

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return self.a
```

Comment: Do we really need four answers to say the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo():
    a = 0
    def bar(self):
        return self.a

f = Foo()
f.bar()
```